# Test Naming Conventions in Golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to unit test a Go package for the first time, and I have a couple of errors in the same file.

```
type FooErr int
type BarErr int

func (e *FooErr) Error () string {
    return "A Foo Error has occurred"
}

func (e *BarErr) Error () string {
    return "A Bar Error has occurred"
}
```

However, all naming conventions seem to look like this `func TestXxx(*testing.T)` ([from the `testing` package documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/)). This would mean my testing file would look like this:

```
func TestError (t *testing.T) { ... } // FooErr
func TestError (t *testing.T) { ... } // BarErr
```

Which is obviously two functions of the same signature. What is the recommended method for handling this?

Comment: `TestFooError` and `TestBarError` maybe?

Comment: I mean, it will work, but I'd like to know the best practice, since there is a formally expressed convention for test names.

Comment: With Go1.4 (Q4 2014), you now also have `TestMain()`: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26648324/6309)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are a few things to consider here:

### Errors

Package-level exported error values are typically named `Err` followed by something, for instance `ErrTimeout` [here](http://golang.org/src/pkg/testing/iotest/reader.go?h=ErrTimeout#L69).  This is done so that clients of your package can do something like

```
if err := yourpkg.Function(); err == yourpkg.ErrTimeout {
  // timeout
} else if err != nil {
  // some other error
}
```

To facilitate this, they are often created either with `errors.New`:

```
// Error constants
var (
  ErrTimeout = errors.New("yourpkg: connect timeout")
  ErrInvalid = errors.New("yourpkg: invalid configuration")
)
```

or with a custom, unexported type:

```
type yourpkgError int

// Error constants
var (
  ErrTimeout yourpkgError = iota
  ErrSyntax
  ErrConfig
  ErrInvalid
)

var errText = map[yourpkgError]string{
  ErrTimeout: "yourpkg: connect timed out",
  ...
}

func (e yourpkgError) Error() string { return errText[e] }
```

One advantage of the latter approach is that it cannot compare equal with a type from any other package.

In the case where you need some extra data inside the error, the name of the type ends in `Error`:

```
type SyntaxError struct {
  File           string
  Line, Position int
  Description    string
}

func (e *SyntaxError) Error() string {
  return fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d:%d: %s", e.File, e.Line, e.Position, e.Description)
}
```

which, in contrast to the previous equality check, requires a type assertion:

```
tree, err := yourpkg.Parse(file)
if serr, ok := err.(*SyntaxError); ok {
  // syntax error
} else if err != nil {
  // other error
}
```

In either case, it is important to document your code so that users of your package understand when they will be used and what functions might return them.

### Tests

Tests are often named after the unit that they're testing.  In many cases, you won't test error conditions separately, so `TestError` is not a name that should come up very often.  The name of the test itself merely has to be unique, however, and is not constrained to match anything in the code under test in the same way that examples are.  When you're testing multiple conditions of a piece of code, it is often best to formulate the test as a [Table Driven Test](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/TableDrivenTests).  That wiki page has some good examples, but to demonstrate error checking, you might do this:

```
func TestParse(t *testing.T) {
  tests := []struct{
    contents string
    err      error
  }{
    {"1st", nil},
    {"2nd", nil},
    {"third", nil},
    {"blah", ErrBadOrdinal},
    {"", ErrUnexpectedEOF},
  }
  for _, test := range tests {
    file := strings.NewReader(test.contents)
    if err := Parse(file); err != test.err {
      t.Errorf("Parse(%q) error %q, want error %q", test.contents, err, test.err)
    }
    // other stuff
  }
}
```

If you do need a special test function for a unit that does something weird and doesn't fit in the main test, you'd typically name it something descriptive like `TestParseTimeout` that includes both the unit and the behavior you're testing.

Comment: Thank you for the well-written, elaborate answer! I see the error of my ways! +1 :)

Comment: The array of structs is an awesome way to do tests, thank you.

Answer (score 11):

I would follow the convention for example functions documented in the [overview](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#pkg-overview) section of the testing package:

"The naming convention to declare examples for a function F, a type T and method M on type T are:"

```
func ExampleF() { ... }
func ExampleT() { ... }
func ExampleT_M() { ... }
```

The naming convention for example functions is needed for godoc, but I'd follow the same convention for tests, TestT_M, for consistency.

Comment: "Multiple example functions for a package/type/function/method may be provided by appending a distinct suffix to the name. The suffix must start with a lower-case letter." e.g.: `ExampleT_M_suffix() { ... }`

Comment: Can someone provide real examples of this? With suffixes.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to have the Xxx part of `TestXxx` match an actual function name. The convention of prefixing the tests with `Test` is enough for the `go test` command to pick them up.

Like Alex Lockwood says in his comment, you could use TestFooError and TestBarError if you want.

Comment: `Test` alone works, `TestXxx` works, but note that `Testxxx` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

[Go 1.4 (Q4 2014)](http://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.4#minor_library_changes) will add one more naming convention for test methods:

> The testing package has a new facility to provide more control over running a set of tests.
>   If the test code contains a function:

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M)
```

> that function will be called instead of running the tests directly.
>   The [`M` struct](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/testing/#M) contains methods to access and run the tests.